# Failed to validate receiptError: failed to validate purchase using Node.js

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, in-app-purchase, web-deployment

I am trying to set up a node.js server to validate receipts from `AppStore connect` In App Purchases I have set up. I have followed  this https://github.com/voltrue2/in-app-purchase library but I'm getting an error response saying my receipt is not defined and `failed to validate receipt`. I'm I doing anything wrong here. I'm still testing on a local server. I want to get it to work before hosting it on `Heroku`. What would I be doing wrong here?

```
const iap = require('in-app-purchase');

iap.config({
  applePassword: 'MySecretKey',
  test: true
});

iap.setup()
  .then(() => {
    iap.validateOnce(receipt, appleSecretString).then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
  })
    .catch((error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Validation error' + error);
    }
});

iap.validate(iap.APPLE, function (error, appleResponse) {
  console.log(iap.APPLE);
  if (error) {
    console.log('Failed to validate receipt' + error);
  }
  if (iap.isValidated(appleResponse)) {
    console.log('Validation successful');
  }
});
```

Here are the logs

> > iapserver:server Listening on port 3000 +0ms
> >     Validation errorReferenceError: receipt is not defined
> >     apple
> >     Failed to validate receiptError: failed to validate purchase

Answer (score 0):

From the error is seems like you're not actually passing the receipt file into the `validateOnce` function. Somewhere before that code runs you need to set:

```
const receipt = req.query.receipt;
```

And invoke your API with something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/verifyReceipt?receipt=<YOUR_RECEIPT_DATA>
```

You can [verify your receipt](https://www.revenuecat.com/apple-receipt-checker) beforehand manually to make sure it's valid.

Putting this all together, you'd get something like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

const iap = require('in-app-purchase');


app.get('/verifyReceipt', function(req, res){

  const receipt = req.query.receipt;

  iap.config({
    applePassword: 'MySecretKey',
    test: true
  });

  iap.setup()
    .then(() => {
      iap.validateOnce(receipt, appleSecretString).then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
    })
      .catch((error) => {
      if (error) {
          console.log('Validation error' + error);
          res.status(400).send({valid: false});
      }
  });

  iap.validate(iap.APPLE, function (error, appleResponse) {
    console.log(iap.APPLE);
    if (error) {
      console.log('Failed to validate receipt' + error);
      res.status(400).send({valid: false});
    }
    if (iap.isValidated(appleResponse)) {
      console.log('Validation successful');
      res.status(200).send({valid: true});
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Note that this will only verify the receipt at purchase, if you're implementing subscriptions you also need to periodically refresh the receipt to make sure they user didn't cancel. Here's a good guide on implementing subscriptions: [iOS Subscriptions are Hard](https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/ios-subscriptions-are-hard-d9b29c74e96f)

Comment: do you have a site for android receipt validation too?