# How can i send receipt data using Swift to Node.js server

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm currently trying to verify `IAP` receipts of user subscriptions in iOS. At first i make a post request that gets me the receipt data from the receipt currently stored in `Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL`. I'm able to get use this receipt data in my server to verify the receipt which works pretty well. However this receipt data string is hard coded in `Node` which is specific to a certain user. How can i be able to send this receipt string to my server for any receipt depending on any user to be verified. Here is both my Swift and server code. Apple says in the documentation

> > To retrieve the receipt data, use the appStoreReceiptURL method of NSBundle to locate the app’s receipt, and then read the entire file. Send this data to your server—as with all interactions with your server, the details are your responsibility.

I would like to get the receipt data and send it to my server.

```
func getReceipt() {
    if let receiptUrl = receiptUrl {
        do {
            let purchaseReceipt = try Data(contentsOf: receiptUrl)
            self.validatePurchaseReceipt(pReceiptData: purchaseReceipt)
        } catch {
            let receiptRefreshRequest = SKReceiptRefreshRequest(receiptProperties: nil)
            receiptRefreshRequest.delegate = self
            receiptRefreshRequest.start()
        }
    }
}

func validatePurchaseReceipt(pReceiptData: Data) {
    let base64encodedReceipt = pReceiptData.base64EncodedString()
    let secretKey = "myAppstoreConnectSecretKey"
    let requestReceiptDict = ["receipt-data": base64encodedReceipt, "password": secretKey]
    guard JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(requestReceiptDict) else { return }
    do {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestReceiptDict)
        let validationString = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
        guard let validationUrl = URL(string: validationString) else { return }
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        var request = URLRequest(url: validationUrl, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let task = session.uploadTask(with:request, from: data) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            do {
                let purchaseReceiptJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
                print("Success retrieved json:\(purchaseReceiptJSON)")
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

This is my server code

```
const express = require('express');
const requirePromise = require('request-promise');
const app = express();

let verificationURL = 'https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt';
let secretKey = 'myAppstoreConnectSecretKey';
let receiptData = 'MIIntgYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIInpzCCJ6MCAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIIXVwYJKoZIhvcNAQcBoIIXSASCFetc'
const options = {
  url: verificationURL,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    json: true
};

options.form = JSON.stringify({
    'receipt-data': receiptData,
    'password': secretKey
});

requirePromise(options).then((resData) => {
    console.log(resData);
    return resData;
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to be using your server to validate receipts (which you should) then the `validatePurchaseReceipt` method should be calling your server, not the `/verifyReceipt` endpoint. The receipt data is passed to your server exactly like you do with `requestReceiptDict`.

Also, the `secretKey` *should* be hardcoded on your server - not anywhere on the client.

Here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54261816/3166209

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes more sense